# How to resolve exceeded agent connection timeout period?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mtm

When running automation suite in Visual Studio + MTM. I am getting the below error..

```
TestOutcome 'Warning'; Message 'Agent 'vstfs:///LabManagement/TestMachine/575' exceeded agent connection timeout period.'
```

Does it need agent to be restarted or any other resolution??

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of timeouts and settings for the controller and agent:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934570.aspx

The time out in the error message refers to the first one on the list.  The article explains where and how to adjust the different timeouts.  Be mindful of what is "agent" and what is "controller" when looking for config files, these are likely on different computers.